# 0th-order differential operator vs. 1st-order differential operator on a vector bundle $(E, \pi,M)$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, manifolds, vector-bundles

Consider a vector bundle $(E,\pi,M)$. A 0th-order differential operator on $E$ is a $C^\infty(M)$-linear endomorphism $\Gamma E\rightarrow\Gamma E$. $\Gamma E$ is the set of sections on $M$.

A 1st-order differential operator on $E$ is an $\mathbb R$ linear map $D:\Gamma E\rightarrow \Gamma E$ such that for each $u\in C^\infty(M)$, the map

$\Gamma E\rightarrow\Gamma E,\quad \mu\mapsto D(u\mu)-uD(\mu)$

is a 0th-order differential operator.

But it seems to me it is impossible to construct the operator $D$ from a 0th-order differential operator. Consider a smooth function $f\in C^\infty(M)$, then $f\mu\in\Gamma E$, therefore,

$f\mu\mapsto D(uf\mu)-uD(f\mu), \forall u\in C^\infty(M)$     ------- Eq.(1)

But $uf$ is an arbitrary smooth function on $M$,

$f\mu\mapsto D(uf\mu)-ufD(\mu)$    ------- Eq.(2)

Comparing the two equations Eq.(1) and (2) gives

$uD(f\mu)=ufD(\mu)\Rightarrow D(f\mu)=fD(\mu)$

However, $f$ is actually arbitrary, so $\mu\mapsto D(u\mu)-uD(\mu)=0, \forall u\in C^\infty(M)$.

Probably I misunderstand the definitions? Please help me out. Thank you!

---

Another question, how to prove the map $\mu\mapsto D(u\mu)-uD(\mu)$ is $C^\infty(M)$ linear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't follow your derivation that $D(u\mu) - uD(\mu)=0$.  But I think you're misinterpreting the definition. It means that $D$ is a first-order differential operator if and only if for each $u\in C^\infty(M)$, the map $F_u\colon \Gamma E \to \Gamma E$ defined by $F_u(\mu) = D(u\mu) - u D(\mu)$ is linear over $C^\infty(M)$ in $\mu$. More specifically, this means that the following identity holds for all $u,f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $\mu\in \Gamma E$:
$$
D(uf\mu) - u D(f\mu) = f\big(D(u\mu)) - u D(\mu)\big).
$$

As for your second question, how you would prove it depends on specifically what the operator $D$ is.  Here's an example.  Let $E = TM$, the tangent bundle of $M$, and let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$. Consider the map $\mathscr L_X\colon \Gamma(TM)\to \Gamma(TM)$, i.e., Lie differentiation by $X$.  A straightforward computation based on the properties of the Lie dervative shows that for all $u,f\in C^\infty(M)$ and all $Y\in \Gamma(TM)$, 
$$
\mathscr L_X(ufY) - u \mathscr L_X(fY) = f\big( \mathscr L_X(uY) - u \mathscr L_XY\big).
$$
Thus $\mathscr L_X$ is a first-order differential operator.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. But there is not any general proof to show the linearity of the 1st-order differential operator, is there? If so, what a pity!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You presented this as a _definition_ of a first-order differential operators, so there's nothing to prove. (Actually, it is more precisely a definition of a _linear_ first-order differential operator.) If you have another definition of a linear first-order differential operator in mind, then you could try proving that the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: I actually want to verify this definition is well-defined. Your answer shows that it is well-defined in the case of Lie differentiation, which removes my worry. But I would like to see if it can be verified in a general situation.

Comment: I'm still confused. The definition of first-order differential operator that you wrote down does not involve any choices, so of course it's well-defined. I didn't show it's well-defined in the case of Lie differentiation, I just showed that Lie differentiation satisfies the definition.

Comment: Sorry, I have difficulty in expressing my concern, or maybe my concern isn't a concern... anyway, thank you!